# Flex + Mate + WebServiceInvoker : Changing the WSDL according to FlashVars

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, web-services, mate

I have a Mate project with a WebService tag instance in the EventMap (which I'm using within various event handlers). I'd quite like to be able to set the wsdl property of the WebService via flashvars, but I'm not entirely sure where or how I could do that.

I know I can access flashvars via the Application.application.parameters collection, but I don't seem to have access to the Application instance during the load event of the WebService...

I suspect there's either something subtle or something blatantly obvious that I'm managing to overlook :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partly this was due to me not putting the parameter in the correct section of index.template.html (if everything's fine, it's the SECOND section that gets called, not the first), and partly it was my misunderstanding the behaviour of the Application and WebService classes (why oh why does it not cache the wsdl?)

I ended up adding a bindable public variable on the event map instance, then setting that variable in the creationComplete handler of the main application. I could probably have done this entirely within the event map, but it would have been a little more convoluted.